# How can I show alert in parent window from child popup window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to show an alert in the parent window and then refresh it when closing the child window. I tried:

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
        function refreshParent() {
                        window.opener.focus();
                        window.opener.alert('Testing');
                        window.opener.location.reload();
        }
```

This does show the alert in the parent, but I guess because the child is within the parent, the child window js freezes till I hit ok in the parent window. I can live with that, but the problem is, the parent window doesn't seem to get the focus when I show the alert, so the alert ends up being hidden behind the popup window. Any advice guys?

Comment: Is this the same across all browsers?  It might just be implementation specific.

Comment: I tested in FF and Chrome, and the issue is same in both

Comment: Have you tried using [window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp) like:

    window.parent.alert("message");

I am not sure if that will solve your focus problem but it is worth a try.

Comment: just tried it, result is still same.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
refreshParent();
}

        function refreshParent() {

                        window.parent.focus();
                        window.parent.alert("message");
                        window.parent.location.reload();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you , i just used the window.alert instead of alert and solved the problem. Tnx